# SQLServer Generate Date to Row Between Two Dates

Tags: sql-server

I have one table as follows

```
ID(INT), PeopleID (INT), StartDate (DATE), EndDate(DATE)
1, 1, 2018-01-01, 2018-12-01
2, 1, 2017-01-01, 2017-02-01
```

What I really want to do is have the query output to be like this

```
ID(INT), PeopleID (INT), StartDate (DATE), EndDate(DATE), GenerateDate(DATE)
1, 1, 2018-01-01, 2018-12-01, 2018-01-01
1, 1, 2018-01-01, 2018-12-01, 2018-02-01
1, 1, 2018-01-01, 2018-12-01, 2018-03-01
1, 1, 2018-01-01, 2018-12-01, 2018-04-01
1, 1, 2018-01-01, 2018-12-01, 2018-05-01
1, 1, 2018-01-01, 2018-12-01, 2018-06-01
1, 1, 2018-01-01, 2018-12-01, 2018-07-01
1, 1, 2018-01-01, 2018-12-01, 2018-08-01
1, 1, 2018-01-01, 2018-12-01, 2018-09-01
1, 1, 2018-01-01, 2018-12-01, 2018-10-01
1, 1, 2018-01-01, 2018-12-01, 2018-11-01
1, 1, 2018-01-01, 2018-12-01, 2018-12-01
2, 1, 2017-01-01, 2017-02-01, 2017-01-01
2, 1, 2017-01-01, 2017-02-01, 2017-02-01
```

I have tried this query.

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime,@EndDate datetime;
SET @StartDate = (select StartDate from x.date);
SET @EndDate = (select EndDate from x.date);

WITH CTE AS
     (SELECT @StartDate as theDate
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, theDate)
        FROM CTE
       WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, theDate) <= @EndDate
     )
SELECT CAST(theDate AS DATE) AS GenerateDate
    FROM CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

but ended up with an error message because it has more than one value, I'm stuck. Can someone please give me any answer/tips/hint?

Comment: what is this Generate Date can you tell the logic ?

Comment: Research tally table and calendar table. There are a few methods to create these which you have shown. Then you will simply join to it with the between operator

Comment: Oh and at the top of your script you are going to want to use min for the `@StartDate` and max for the `@EndDate`. ThIs is where your error is coming from. Then you will have your calendar table or CTE in this case that you can join to. Posting the error message is always a good idea

Comment: @Amitchauhan i want to display all the date from two date ranges

Comment: @scsimon the error was `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, peopleid INT, startdate DATE, enddate DATE)
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 1, '1/1/2018', '12/1/2018'), 
(2, 1, '1/1/2017', '2/1/2017')

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, peopleid, startdate, enddate, startdate AS generatedate
    FROM test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, peopleid, startdate, enddate, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, generatedate)
    FROM cte
    WHERE generatedate < enddate
)
SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY id, generatedate
```

Result:

```
id  peopleid    startdate   enddate     generatedate
1   1           2018-01-01  2018-12-01  2018-01-01
1   1           2018-01-01  2018-12-01  2018-02-01
1   1           2018-01-01  2018-12-01  2018-03-01
1   1           2018-01-01  2018-12-01  2018-04-01
1   1           2018-01-01  2018-12-01  2018-05-01
1   1           2018-01-01  2018-12-01  2018-06-01
1   1           2018-01-01  2018-12-01  2018-07-01
1   1           2018-01-01  2018-12-01  2018-08-01
1   1           2018-01-01  2018-12-01  2018-09-01
1   1           2018-01-01  2018-12-01  2018-10-01
1   1           2018-01-01  2018-12-01  2018-11-01
1   1           2018-01-01  2018-12-01  2018-12-01
2   1           2017-01-01  2017-02-01  2017-01-01
2   1           2017-01-01  2017-02-01  2017-02-01
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8ad9d/2

Comment: Thanks, this help me a lot, i make some modification:

`DECLARE @test TABLE (ID INT, PeopleID INT, StartDate DATE, EndDate DATE)
INSERT INTO @test (ID, PeopleID, StartDate, EndDate)
SELECT ID, PeopleID, StartDate, EndDate FROM MySchema.MyTable

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ID, PeopleID, StartDate, EndDate, EndDate AS generatedate
    FROM @test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, PeopleID, StartDate, EndDate, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, generatedate)
    FROM cte
    WHERE generatedate < EndDate
)
SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY ID, generatedate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`